# Show UITableView after popViewController to parent view in the state before pushing to the child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have a `UITableView` initially displayed on the half of the screen in the parent view controller. There is also button in the parent view controller. When Im clicking on this button I'm displaying `childViewController` by using method

`self.navigationViewController pushViewController: animated:`.

In the time when Im clicking on the `UIButton` the `UITableView` is hidden from the screen. All I want to do is to display my parent view controller in the state before pushing `childViewController`. So when the user tap on the "back" `UIBarButton` I want to present parent view controller only with the `UIButton` -- **but without UITableView** --.

So my problem is that when Im calling

`self.navigationViewController popViewController: animated:`

the `UITableView` is backing to the initial position on the screen.
To be more specific I'm using storyboards and I have `UITableView` initialised as a `IBOutlet`. I tried to fix it by creating delegate method and calling this method in the `viewWillDisapear` but the `UITableView` was still in the same, initial position.

I tried also with `NSNotificationCenter` but the result was the same.

How can I fix it any ideas? 
Let me know if you need some code.

Comment: What do you mean by, "in the time when I'm clicking on the UIButton the UITableView is hidden from the screen"? Are you setting it's hidden property to YES in the button's action method?

Comment: Yes, and also setting user jnteraction enabled to false

Comment: What you're describing shouldn't happen. If you set the table view's hidden property to YES, navigate to another controller, and come back again, it still should be hidden. Are you setting the hidden property to NO somewhere (like viewDidAppear)?

Comment: Naaah, I didn't set hidden property anywhere in methods like viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear. It's weird..

Comment: Are you going back to the first controller with the standard "back" button? You have no code to go back or any segues set up?

Comment: Yes, with the standard back button. It seems to me that the problem is because of UITableView that is set in my storyboard as no hidden, and then when the user is backing to the main view I have the same value as in the storyboard. Even if I change the value of y position in the storyboard and then Im trying to back from the child view controller the parent view is displaying the values from the storyboards. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: No, not without seeing some code. The inability to change the y position might be because of auto layout. If you have that turned on, the table view will revert to its constraints defined position whenever the view needs to be redrawn. That shouldn't affect the hidden property though -- if you've set it in code to YES, then the storyboard value shouldn't matter.